# Download pdf file to iOS using apache cordova

Tags: android, ios, apache, cordova, pdf

I have a very critical problem.

I'm developing mobile app on android and iOS using apahce cordova with visual studio 2015.

My app downloads and opens a pdf file from external direct url using file transfer and file opener plugins.

I've successfully downloaded and opened that file on android on device memory.

but no matter how many time i try to do the same thing on iOS , it never works.

I have tried all directories on that link : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files

All i want is a working example of downloading a file in any directory from external server and open it in iOS using apache cordova.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had the same problem to solve, and used the [file opener 2 plugin](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2), which you use like this:

```
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
            'path/to/file.pdf',
            'application/pdf',
            {
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log('Error opening file:' + e);
                    console.log('path: ' + filePathAndroid);
                },
                success: function() {
                    console.log('File opened successfully');
                    console.log('path: ' + filePathAndroid);
                }
            }
        );
```

This opens the PDF using an action sheet that shows all the possibilities that the device has for handling it (Adobe Reader if installed, iBooks, AirPrint, send to email etc).

You can use the Cordova file plugin to download the PDF from your server and work out a path to it on the local device.

My sample app that shows a range of ways of handling PDFs for Android and iOS can be found [here](https://github.com/simonprickett/pdfjscordova).  There I tried the In App Browser (not great, doesn't work on Android), PDF.js (renders PDF inline in a canvas, but pretty slow and no pinch zoom) and the file opener 2 plugin (most "natural" way to use the device's abilities in my opinion).

Raymond Camden also recently [blogged](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2016/06/26/linking-to-pdfs-in-cordova-apps/) on this subject, you may find his post useful background reading too.

Comment: thank you @simon , but i really need to know where to download the pdf file i have the following code that produce an error .

http://pho.to/ACd7A